# Can I have two apps with different bundle IDs and same name?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, build, app-store-connect

On iTunes Connect, I have an iPhone app which is already live.
Now I want to submit an iPad version of it - **for iPad only** - and I read that the Bundle ID must be different.

Can I still use the same app name though?

e.g.:

iPhone app name: "My App"
iPhone app bundle ID: com.foo.bar

iPad app name: "My App"
iPad app bundle ID: com.foo.bar.ipad

or I need to distinguish it somehow? e.g. "My App for iPad"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't have two apps with same name.

Bundle Id should be different also. You can't have same bundle id too.

Comment: OK. Out of curiosity, if I remove the iPhone app from iTunes, will I be able to reuse its name for the iPad version?

Comment: As long as i know,I don't think that is also possible mate.